# Book about a little girl that found that if she pulled the plug of a bathtub full of water she could leave home

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in the mid to late fifties.

The little girl was very withdrawn and shy. She enjoyed spending time alone but somehow discovered when taking a bath if she pulled the drain plug before she got out of the tub she was taken outside to a pond in the woods where she made friends with all the woodland creatures. She would then visit them on a regular basis. Can't recall how she got back into her home.

Answer (score 11):

This appears to be [*Clarinda*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22071039-clarinda) (1944) by Frances Duncombe, but it seems to be a non-genre children's book.

[image: Cover of "Clarinda" showing the title character sitting on grass with a collection of small animals]

A contemporary [New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/1944/06/25/archives/clarinda-by-frances-duncombe-illustrated-by-angela-133-pp-new-york.html) about it begins:

> NOT every little girl who is as strong-minded as Clarinda finds so convenient and fascinating an escape from the rigors of home discipline as did she. By the happy chance of meeting a strange duck in her bathtub Clarinda discovered that she could go down the drain-pipe and come up in a woodland pond filled with amphibious new friends ready to help her throw dull care away.

Comment: That sounds pretty fantastical to me.